# Youtube Stopped Playing Videos

Tags: youtube

Since a couple of days ago, youtube stopped playing videos. They come up with a
black screen and no controls. The comments etc. below are there. To the right,
there isn't very much, except for the fragment "Un". I've reinstalled flash.

I could easily show with a screenshot, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do that here.

This is on Firefox. Firefox on Windows 7 works OK.

Comment: Same here with Mint 17. This is evidently related to the Firefox 34 update. I tried switching YouTube to use HTML5 video and it will play and I can hear the audio, but the video is still black. This is not an issue in Chromium.